# Increment string in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'd like to increment a string value in MySQL. It will be used in a query to get the first available value.

I tried `CONV(...)` with base 36 but it does not cover every case. The string can have a different structure depending on some internal parameters.

Possibles structures :

```
  pattern                   |    sample    |    incremented
----------------------------|--------------|-------------------
 ([0-9]+)                   |        1239  |           1240
 ([A-Z]+)                   |        ABCD  |           ABCE
 ([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)           |       1234A  |          1234B
 ([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)           |       ABCD1  |          ABCD2
 ([A-Z]+)-([0-9]+)-([A-Z]+) | ABCD-1239-Z  |    ABCD-1240-A
 etc.                       |              |
```

Is it possible in MySQL?

Comment: Why, for the sake of anything that's holy in this world of computers would you want to "increment" a string? Anything is possible, the question is what are you willing to give up for it to work?

Comment: I need this to get the first available value in a column for a given pattern. I don't know what I'm willing to give up actually, maybe all that seems reasonable.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You arrived at something that you *think* is a solution, and you're looking for the means to achieve it. However, as always, you probably chose the wrong approach. The real question is *why* do you need first available value in a column? What is it that you're doing really? You are forgetting that databases are concurrent systems, which means that there are many connections operating on the same data. What about ensuring you don't get duplicate records? You need to worry about many factors, I'd suggest explaining your problem in detail and look for a different approach.

Comment: Here's some explanation but that's actually not the question so I won't edit my post. These values are used to identify a person (but not used as PK). There's different types of persons and each type has a pattern (like described above). I need the first available value to *suggest* it to the user that wants to add a person. I think the fact that databases are concurrent systems is not an issue, my back-end (j2ee) can lock/release the method call if needed - please correct me if I'm wrong. By the way, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short answer: No.

Long answer: You could write a stored procedure that does this (or do it with PHP/JAVA/...). But still it's difficult because there is no clear rule how to increment a string.

Take your last example: ABCD-1239-Z to ABCD-1240-A
You need a rule that looks for - in the string and never changes this, but changes the chars before, handling them as numbers!

Let me give another possible pattern (something like this will probably happen): Z-Z
How to increase this? Will it become AA-A or 1A-A or Z-AA?

If you need to increment, than stick to a number. Everything else will get you into trouble.

Comment: I'm already writting a stored procedure to get the first available value so this will be included. The rule is the regular expression actually. You are right about the pattern you gave, didn't think about that. The pattern should be more specific like this `([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]{1})` for example. You make me think that it won't be possible in MySQL but I keep looking for.

Comment: By the way, I can't stick to numbers. It would be *really* simpler otherwise.

Comment: Using PHP, it's trivial. It allows you do use the increment operator on the string